# Why prototype is not available in simple JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to understand the JavaScript prototype and I am bit confused.There are tons of tutorials out there and each has different explanation on it. So I don't know where to start with.

So far I have created a simple JavaScript object

```
var a = {flag : 1}
```

In [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype), I read that

> All objects in JavaScript are descended from Object

But I couldn't find the prototype for this object **a** `a.prototype` gives me `undefined`

Then I found the prototype is available in `a.constructor.prototype`. When I create a function `var myfunc = function() {}` and then `myfunc.prototype` is available. So the prototype property is directly available on functions and not on objects.

Please help me to understand this and what is that `a.constructor`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This exact question was asked and answered about a week ago.  I will attempt to find the duplicate.

Comment: var a = {}; is the shorthand for new Object(). Which you know is the root of all objects

Comment: Another duplicate explanation: [Extending prototype on object literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29977892/extending-prototype-on-object-literal/29977926#29977926)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every function can be called as a constructor (with `new` keyword).

```
function Dog() {
  this.legs = 4;
}
```

When you call it as a normal function, `var dog = Dog()`, it will define `window.legs` in browsers to be `4` (something a bit different but related if in Node.JS), and set `dog` to `undefined`.

However, if you call it as a constructor, as `var dog = new Dog()`, it will make a new object, and set its `constructor` to this function, and assign this new object to `dog`. It will set its internal prototype (which can be accessed in *some* browsers as `dog.__proto__`) to the constructor's prototype (`Dog.prototype`). Or, in pseudocode,

```
var dog = {
  legs: 4
};
dog.constructor = Dog;
dog.__proto__ = Dog.prototype; // same as dog.constructor.prototype
```

Thus, `dog.constructor.prototype` is not, strictly speaking, the prototype of `dog`, it is the object that will get assigned to the prototype when the constructor function is run. And in particular, `Dog.prototype` is *not* prototype of the `Dog` function (just the prototype that its instances will acquire). The reason `prototype` is not available on non-functions is because non-functions can't be used as constructors, so it makes no sense to have it (since its only function is to be copied to constructed instance objects' `__proto__`).

The object in your example still has a prototype, but not directly accessible; you can either go the hacky route in the browsers that allow it (`a.__proto__`), or ask the browser nicely (`Object.getPrototypeOf(a)`).

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. You have mentioned in pseudocode dog.__proto__ = Dog.constructor.prototype;
But dog.__proto__ == Dog.constructor.prototype is showing 'false'
Could you please explain.?

Comment: Typo, sorry. Should be `dog.constructor.prototype` (which is same as `Dog.prototype`). Edited.

Comment: Could you please explain this line "And in particular, Dog.prototype is not prototype of the Dog function (just the prototype that its instances will acquire)"

Comment: `Dog.prototype` is prototype of `dog` (i.e. of `new Dog()`), not of `Dog` (but we will colloquially say that `Dog.prototype` is a Dog prototype). `dog.__proto__` is also prototype of `dog` (as `dog.__proto__` and `Dog.prototype` are the same thing). Meanwhile, `Dog.__proto__` (which is equal to `Object.prototype`, in this case) is the prototype of `Dog` itself. Does that make sense?

Comment: So Dog.prototype is not the prototype of Dog, but the prototype of its instance and Dog.__proto__ is the prototype of Dog, is that correct?

Comment: And in our case Dog.__proto__ is function Empty() {}

Comment: Yes, exactly so. `Dog.prototype` is the prototype of Dog objects (created by `new Dog()`). Prototype of `Dog`, `Dog.__proto__`, is `Function.prototype`,  the prototype for all things created as functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) instead to return you the prototype of `Object`.

To see this in your browser devtools, run the following:

```
var a = {flag: 1};
console.dir(Object.getPrototypeOf(a));
```